# Finding an approach to selecting last recorded value alongside current value for a field in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have part of a database in SQLite as follows:

```
    id   date              position   price   instrument portfolio  sector
    1   "2013-01-02 00:00:00"   162000  30.95   HRL usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    2   "2013-01-02 00:00:00"   195000  25.62   KR  usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    3   "2013-01-02 00:00:00"   137000  36.61   WAG usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    21  "2013-01-03 00:00:00"   162000  32.1    HRL usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    22  "2013-01-03 00:00:00"   195000  25.64   KR  usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    41  "2013-01-04 00:00:00"   162000  33.17   HRL usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    42  "2013-01-04 00:00:00"   195000  25.71   KR  usequity    "Consumer Staples"
    61  "2013-01-07 00:00:00"   195000  25.09   KR  usequity    "Consumer Staples"
```

I'm trying to get the price for the last recorded date by instrument for each instrument so I can calculate a rate of change.

I've researched two ideas on SO:

1. Create a view with a separate rowid sequence and reference that. My reading suggests that that isn't possible i.e.

   `CREATE view px1 AS (SELECT p.date, p.instrument, p.price, COUNT(*) 
      FROM prices as p order by instrument,date asc)`

   doesn't work.
2. Combine the price table twice using something like:

   `SELECT p.date, p.instrument, p.price AS curpx, p1.price AS lastpx 
      FROM prices AS p, prices AS p1 
      WHERE p1.date < MAX(DATETIME(p.date));`

All I've read suggests that this approach should work but that just gives me another error. Could you suggest what the best approach to fixing this would be?

i.e. What SQL query / or approach will give me a list of prices by instrument alongside a second column showing the previous recorded price of the same instrument in a portfolio?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.date, p.instrument, p.price AS curpx,
       (SELECT p2.price
        FROM price p2
        WHERE p2.instrument = p.instrument AND p2.date < p.date
        ORDER BY p2.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) AS lastpx 
FROM prices p;
```

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff. that thudding sound was my jaw dropping in awe at the elegance of this solution.